# creating "login using facebook" in blackberry app

Tags: facebook, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have been researching a lot on implementing logging into my blackberry app using facebook login. I have downloaded the latest BlackBerry Facebook SDK from Sourceforge. I received two jar files and a "not at all useful" readme.pdf. Can somebody kindly tell me how do I use these jar files in my app? I am creating a game app for BlackBerry and I want to give the user, an option of logging in using his/her fb account. I went through that strawberry program classes but I could not find source helping me to login. I have implemented FB in android as well. and it works fine.

Briefing again
1) Help me out with Login using fb account for BlackBerry(using the jar files)

2) Any tutorial link or pdf giving a detailed explanation about using BB FB SDK.

FYI, I am using SDK version 0.8.25. Here is the link for list of different versions https://facebook-bb-sdk.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/facebook-bb-sdk/tags/

Thanks

Comment: no dude i dint continue to work after tat

Answer (score 1):

Check ShowUserScreen class in the strawBerry App,there it will be go thr showuserAsync(),which will somehow invoke the browserfield,and after it will ask login option,and after enter the user and password,it will get thr Fb account,and you will get Information.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I did go through the code you mentioned above. But my query is to locate the exact point where the login action takes place. I found that using NEXT_URL field, the users can login using fb and after that the permissions are requested and stuff, but I am quite apprehensive as to merely declaring the url how will the user navigate to fb home.... I pasted that URL on the browser and saw that it returns "successful" command. Anyways Thanks for your effort

Comment: I dont understand what you are expecting.if you want home page to be displayed,it wont,what it is doing,is that,whatever secretkey,appid and url you have,it will get you to login form of facebook using browserfield (based upon my understanding),once you get logged in,then you get the required access to do access the count like post on wall,show status etc

Comment: My query is simple. I want user to login using his fb account and after successful login and authentication, user must enter my app not go to fb page.I dont want him/her to post on wall or like or comment. its plain simple login/logout issue. Cant we check the login status in simulator? it says 'requesting' and after a while it says error cannot connect

Comment: Yes,It will just go to the login page of facebook,it will get back to your app,send ur id if possible to send the sample code.